# Metamodel of Ruby

Tags: ruby, uml

I wondered where I could find the metamodel of Ruby, for instance an ecore representation for Eclipse EMF or something like that.

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever had a look at https://github.com/mthiede/rgen?

Furthermore, of course you can create a Ecore Metamodel for ruby, you may use the RDT for eclipse.

However, Java+Ecore specializes to create external DSLs, while ruby as a dynamic language may offer internal DSL (i.e. in the shape of gems).

BUT, still, using MDSD may speed up development a lot - you can validate your models, can create test cases etc.

Answer (score -2):

EMF is java oriented because using EMF tags inside Java code. It is therefore impossible to have a ruby metamodel within Eclipse modeling framework wit EMF.

Comment: That's not really true.  I think OP is asking for a model that describes the main concepts in Ruby and how they relate.  It's entirely possible to create such a model in UML - and so by extension to represent it in Ecore.

Comment: You create it in UML but not with the current EMF. You can still launch a project and the Eclipse Foundation will certainly sponsor you.

Comment: You can create a Ecore metamodel for any language. The MoDisco eclipse project has metamodels for Java, XML and others (but not ruby yet). Of course, the metamodel will be just that, a metamodel for the language then, you'll need to use other tools to parse Ruby programs and instantiate the metamodel accordingly.

Comment: I agree that you can create as many as you want metamodel from EMF but this is just one more XML serialization. EMF is designed for java at its origin and whatever you do will not change it.